# How to use observer ? Why my observer is not working here?

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

There are two view controller and two view controller class in my project. I want to change the first view controller background colour from the second view controller using notification and observer. But it's not working.
I have noticed that the "changeViewControllerColor(_:)" method is not calling.

First View Controller:

```
import UIKit

let colorChangeNotificationKey = "changeFirstVcColor"

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    let notiName = Notification.Name(rawValue: colorChangeNotificationKey)

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        observer()
    }


    func observer() {

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(FirstViewController.changeViewControllerColor(_:)), name: self.notiName, object: self)
    }

    @objc func changeViewControllerColor(_: NSNotification) {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }


    @IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "secondViewController") as! SecondViewController
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Second View Controller:

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        label.text = "First VC colour is white now"

        let notiName = Notification.Name(rawValue: colorChangeNotificationKey)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notiName, object: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: first of all why don't you use the delegate? it's one to one. if you use NotificationCenter it will be one to many..

Comment: @Harish Actually I am practising. I have used delegate and protocol for the same project and it works. But I wanted to try notification and observer here.

Comment: Look at what the last parameter of addObserver does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SecondViewController:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("changeFirstVcColor"), object: nil)
```

In FirstViewController:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.methodOfReceivedNotification(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("changeFirstVcColor"), object: nil)

@objc func methodOfReceivedNotification(notification: Notification) {}
```

Comment: Good. Fahim, make sure to use delegates if it's just between two viewcontrollers.

Comment: While this answer does solve the issue, some additional explanation would be much more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

When you are adding your observer, you are passing it the object self.

You probably want to pass it a nil.

From the documentation:

> anObject
>
> that is, only notifications sent by this sender are delivered to the
>   observer.
>
> If you pass nil, the notification center doesn’t use a notification’s
>   sender to decide whether to deliver it to the observer.The object whose notifications the observer wants to receive;

So the only thing that it will accept notifications from is itself, which is not likely what you want.

Also, I agree with Harish, you should just use a delegate.